# wordpress get_posts fails with -1 numberposts

Tags: wordpress

i have around 60,000 records for the attachment posts. PHP is running on safe mode so i can not use the set_time_limit.

Code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1);
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
```

The above code gives me a blank page whereas i have kept the errors on. Till numberposts as 4000 it works good, but not further more. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need this ? I don't see any good reasons to get 60000 records in one time...

Comment: i have some wrong data in those posts..i dont know which data is wrong. So i want to recreate meta data of the all the post attachment types.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons why this could happen.

- PHP script runs out of memory. Check the *memory_limit* in your php.ini file. See if you can increase it.
- The script times out. In this case you have to change the *max_execution_time* in your php.ini file
- **Edit**:Also try to add the check the max_input_time setting as well

If for some reason you can't change your php.ini file, then try to retrieve posts in batches.

Comment: 1. already 1 GB memory limit was set...i dont think more than that is required. 2. as i said php is in safe mode so can't set max_execution_time/set time limit etc

Comment: Okay in that case, I guess it's the script which is timing out. Your only option is to do it in batches or disable safe_mode.